# Jenkins - groovy script - get last successful build date in dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: java, date, groovy, jenkins

I'm using "groovy script" plugin as part of my Jenkins build. I wish to find the last successful build date of a job "RegularBuild" however all the examples online e.g.

```
import hudson.model.Build;
def buildA = build("jobA")
println(buildA.getProject().getLastSuccessfulBuild())
```

don't compile even though this seems to be ok.

Not sure how people are using this scripting language but the fundamentals fail. To add to the pain I'm unable to get a valid error comment, all I get is the same error whatever I enter, i.e. the plugin is not helpful at all.

If anyone could help with the correct syntax or even solve the whole problem and provide the date of the last successful build that would be great. One last thing, no xml solutions please as there is nothing in Jenkins that can assign this value to an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE, well that I know of. Thanks

Comment: Mixing 'rants' with question is unlikely to help for useful answers.

Answer (score 20):

Following sample will help you.  I generally find it useful to setup a plugin development environment and see the actual Types and [check documentation](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/)

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def item = Jenkins.instance.getItem("your-job-name")
def  f=item.getLastFailedBuild()

println f.getTime()



def  ff=item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
println ff.getTime().format("YYYY-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss")
println ff.getTime().format("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

**Edit**

(From comments of @Steven the Easily Amused )
   If the Jenkins uses folders , then you need `getItemByFullName("/folder/yourjobname")`

**Edit 2**

Fix date/time format s/MM:SS/mm:ss/  (substitute digits-of-month:milliseconds with minutes:seconds)

Comment: The `Jenkins.instance.getItem("JOB")` call just sets my item = null

Comment: Use 'dd' instead of 'DD' for day of month. 'DD' => "2017-Mar-83 13:03:761". 'dd' => "2017-Mar-24 13:03:547" i.e. 'println d.format("YYYY-MMM-dd HH:MM:SS");'

Comment: If you are using folders, you'll want to use:

`def item = Jenkins.instance..getItemByFullName("/folder/yourjobname")`
Instead of getItem()

Comment: `Jenkins.instance` needs an elevated rights; user must be admin in Jenkins to use it and can't run in a sandbox. Isn't there another way to get this info without elevated rights?

Comment: and, oops, watch out! MM:SS is wrong. MM gives MONTH digits not minutes and SS gives milliseconds. http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rriggs/threeten/threeten-javadoc-dec18/javax/time/format/DateTimeFormatters.html#pattern(java.lang.String)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html I edit/fixed the answer. A year after using the date/time format in this answer I find bad time strings in test reports oopsie :-o ;)

Comment: How can this syntax this fit into a declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

You can also obtain the last successful build like this:

```
def lastSuccessfulBuild = currentBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
```

It doesn't use unsafe methods, so no need for an administrator to [approve the script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/).

It returns a [RunWrapper](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html), so you don't have access to the `getTime()` method <sup>1</sup>.
But you have methods `getTimeInMillis()` and `getStartTimeInMillis()` which you can use to obtain and format the time.

Remember that `lastSuccessfulBuild` might be null, so you should use [Groovy's safe navigation operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator) (`?`) to access it.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> You could access `getTime()` using the raw build instance `lastSuccessfulBuild?.getRawBuild()?.getTime()`, but it would require administrator approval of your script, so not ideal.</sup>