# Last Successful Build Number from Jenkins via email

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have around 30 Jobs in Jenkins for which I need to send out the last successful built revision to the deployment team around 3-4 times a day. This is a time consuming task that I wish to automate.

Is there a script which can retrieve the last successful revision of every job along with the date and time and send that information in one consolidated email?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180785/jenkins-groovy-script-get-last-successful-build-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format) thread to get the last successful build number. To send an email, you will find numerous samples in the net.

Comment: Neethu, What do you mean by your comment?

Comment: import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def item = Jenkins.instance.getItem("My JOb")
def  f=item.getLastFailedBuild()
def  ff=item.getLastSuccessfulBuild() _________ I was getting error when I included the time. With the above code I got the output, but now I have customized my build in such way that the build number would be saved as Revision that is built from SVN. So it is giving me build number instead of revision number

Comment: I want to get the output with the last successful revision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'changeSet' of the 'build' object to get the 'revision' number, below is the code executed in script console to get the 'changeSet' and from that getting 'revision' number.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("fullJobName") 
def lastFailedBuild = item.getLastFailedBuild() 
def lastSuccessfulBuild = item.getLastSuccessfulBuild() 
lastFailedBuild.changeSet.each() { println(it.revision) }
lastSuccessfulBuild.changeSet.each() { println(it.revision) }
```

Comment: Thank you Suresh!!

but It is not giving me the successfull revision. But it is giving me if the last revision is failed for the job. like below.

When i ran for failed job, i got output as below.

135440
Result: hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet@25e772cb

BUt when the job was successfull, this is the output i got

Result: hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet@3abd57c2

Comment: For most of the jobs its working but for few it's not. We are debugging why its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you just to want to provide them the last successful build number for a job, just give them an URL using the rest API:

http://localhost:8090/jenkins/job/some-folder/job/some-other-folder/job/some-job**/api/xml?xpath=workflowJob/lastSuccessfulBuild**

Please notice indeed you just have to append this to your URL job: */api/xml?xpath=workflowJob/lastSuccessfulBuild*, please let us know if it works.

Maybe you can cron a job to generate the XML (from the rest API) for all the jobs you are interested so you dont need to time to time gather that info.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I will try this as well :)