# Jenkins get last successful build tag

Tags: jenkins

How to get Jenkins last successful build number? I tried a few ways and none of them are working..

I'm using `Jenkins 2.309`

`/api/xml` doesn't have `Last successful build` either.

`def buildNumber = Jenkins.instance.getItem('jobName').lastSuccessfulBuild.number` doesn't return anything and the step files.

And then I tried this but it doesn't return the number.

```
                    catchError {
                        script {

                            def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
                            def jobName = "demo-spring-boot"
                            def job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)

                            println "Last successfull build: ${job.getLastSuccessfulBuild()}"
                        }
                    }
```

It returns `Last successfull build: null`

I checked the job history and it does have few succssful builds

Comment: Is your job in a folder? Use "getItemByFullName()".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins - groovy script - get last successful build date in dd-mm-yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180785/jenkins-groovy-script-get-last-successful-build-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [List Jenkins job build detials for last one year along with the user who triggered the build]()https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509896/598141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```groovy
def lastSuccessfulBuildId = currentBuild.previousSuccessfulBuild?.id
println lastSuccessfulBuildId
```

(I put `?` because there could be no successful builds)